# How can I add a specific Shopify menu programmatically?

Tags: shopify, shopify-template

Say for example, I wanted to add a custom section within the page and I wanted to display a menu in that section.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use :

```
{% for link in linklists.main-menu.links %}
      <a href="{{ link.url }}">{{ link.title }}</a>
{% endfor %}
```

And change main-menu with your handle.

For example if you create a menu called Custom Navigation, your handle will be `custom-navigation`

And you will use :

```
{% for link in linklists.custom-navigation.links %}
```

You can find documentation about linklist object [here](https://help.shopify.com/en/themes/liquid/objects/linklist)

Comment: Hello @Gin, if the anwer is right for you, you can accept the answer and / or upvote it :) reference : https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers